# Sample java app shared anchors not returning an anchor number

Tags: android, azure, arcore, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to create a simple android app which allows me to save and share Azure Spatial Anchors across devices by cloning this repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples.git and following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices  But right now when I try to share and item in this app it returns to the screen Anchor Number: https://mikessharingservice.azurewebsites.net and I have no anchor number to enter into the locate section of this app

I simply cloned this app and followed the instructions to create an Azure Spatial Anchor Service which seems to be working fine as I can create and locate anchors in the app.  I'm just unable to get an anchor number back from the "Shared" example.  I also have already created the App Service and Service plan which seem to be working fine and have added the URL to the SharedActivity.java class

Comment: Probably you should try Cloud Anchors API by Google

Comment: Are you able to save the new anchors in the cloud service? What message is the API returning?

Comment: Hi Mike were you able to resolve this issue?